# Bootstrap : how to place a scrollbar on a media-list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I am trying out the container-fluid
and am unable to get a scrollbar on the vertical divide.
( i would like to place a scrollable list within that div)

jsfiddle result : http://jsfiddle.net/wMHGQ/3/embedded/result/

I would like the media-list to be scrollable

jsfiddle edit : http://jsfiddle.net/wMHGQ/3/

is there a built in class to do this ? 
Thanks

code

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="main_part" class="span9 main_part"></div>
        <div id="my_list" class="span3 pull-right">
        <ul class="media-list">
            <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                  <p>Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla.</p>
               </div>
              </li>
            <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                  Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla.</div>
            </li>
            ... scrollable for more requests ..

            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an specific height to the div and then set overflow : auto in your css. With this if your content doesn't fit in your div then a scrollbar will appear.

Comment: i would like the middle content to span the middle area and thus not want to set a specific height. the side-content (media-list) would be the same height as that of the .main_part.. how can i do that ?

Comment: The thing is that the scrollbars are shown when you have an specific height and the content doesn't fit on it.  But if you don't specify a height value your div will start growing vertically when new content is added to it.

Comment: thanks..but what would be a good suggestion to have some sort of dynamic height setting so that look and feel is consistent without being fixed .. ?

Comment: Maybe you can set your height to be a percent value.

Comment: thanks for the input .. finally used jquery to get the height of the .main_part and set that to the list .

Answer (score 0):

You can set max-height to your media Ul and overflow: auto.